# Using Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I need to write a script which merges a list with a dictionary to create a third dictionary. I'm pretty new to programming and am struggling with the basics here.

So far I've created the following class which generates a list of dates. I have another class which generates a dictionary and I want to basically create a third dictionary which contains the dates and data which do not exist already in the first list. 
Any ideas how I should do this? Thanks.

```
class StartList: IDisposable
{
    private readonly string[] names = new[] { "name1", "name2", "name3"};

    private SqlConnection conn;
    private Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>> startData = new Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>();

    public StartList()
    {
        this.conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameCon"].ConnectionString);
        this.conn.Open();
    }

    private void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.conn != null)
        {
            if (this.conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.conn.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }

            this.conn.Dispose();
            this.conn = null;
        }
    }

    public void ImportStartData()
    {
        foreach (string name in this.names)
        {
            this.startData.Add(name, this.ImportStartData(name));
        }
    }

    public List<DateTime> ImportStartData(string name)
    {
        List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();

        string sqlCommand = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}_Index ", name);

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, this.conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(reader.GetDateTime(0));
                }
            }

        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your method "ImportStartData" is bizarre.  That method is iterating over the entries in "this.names" and then proceeds to add entries into the self-same "this.names".

Comment: and `this.names` is `readonly`.  I don't think I understand.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in ImportStartData, should have been adding to startData, not names. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to modify the below code block 
From:

```
 public void ImportStartData()
    {
        foreach (string name in this.names)
        {
            this.names.Add(name, this.ImportStartData(name));
        }
    }
```

To:

```
public void ImportStartData()
    {
        foreach (string name in this.names)
        {
            if(!startData.ContainsKey(name)) //If this check is not done, then Dictionary will throw, duplicate key exception.
            {
               this.startData.Add(name, this.ImportStartData(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyway, the better approach would be, if possible first read the **name** as well as **Date** from database, possibly into a `DataTable` and then using LINQ/foreach loop, group the results by name.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Siva.

Comment: I'm not sure about your suggestion. I probably didn't explain the goal properly. I am ultimately updating a number of SQL tables with new data gathered from an Excel sheet. I start by pulling the existing data from SQL and then I pull the excel data into dictionaries. Then I take the new dictionaries and remove the old data which already exists in the List which we populated from SQL.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to merge the existing SQL data with the data from Excel sheet and then write the merged data back into SQL tables ?

Comment: Not exactly, I just want a third dictionary containing only the new data, then I import that to sql.

Comment: So the excel and sql will be identical except for one or two new entries on the excel file.